# Understanding EDT and sharing objects?

Tags: java, multithreading, event-dispatch-thread

Hi I'm trying to understand EDT vs. Multithreading, hoping someone could correct me if this doesn't make sense.

First I put the creating process of the GUI in its own thread which is
then added to the EDT

```
public class Main 
{
static ServerGui serverGui;
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()  {
        public void run()   {
            try{
                serverGui = new ServerGui();
                serverGui.frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();    }} });}}
```

In my GUI I created the ServerDataHandler object sdh

```
public class ServerGui {
public ServerDataHandler sdh = new ServerDataHandler();

public JFrame frame;

public ServerGui() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setType(Type.NORMAL);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600); }  }
```

Now from another thread, I wish to work with that sdh object, and use some of the methods
that it has.. e.g. sdh.writeToFile(); so here are my questions

1. as I want to use the same object do I need to do it like I've down below?.
2. Do I need to synchronize the ServerDataHandler class when e.g. in my case the method writes down to a file? I suspect I do
3. When would I need to use 'invokeLater'? is that just when I'm changing in the actual GUI?

Client

```
public class Client implements Runnable {

private Socket clientSocket;

public Client(Socket clientSocket) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

@Override
public void run() {
    Main.serverGui.sdh.writeToFile();} }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Classes and objects**

The Main, Client, ServerGui, and ServerDataHandler classes you have created are just that, classes. When you call a class's constructor, you create an object that is an instance of the class.

Each thread weaves its way through the objects in the JVM, following the execution path as a method in one object calls a method in another object. So objects just sit in the JVM and are not specifically bound to threads.

**Threads**

Also inside the JVM live multiple threads. You can create and destroy them yourself, using methods in the `java.lang.Thread` class. But the main thread and the The Event Dispatch Thread are created for you.

An object that's an instance of a `Runnable` class can be created in one thread and then handed over to be run by another thread. This is what you do when you call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`. You create an anonymous `Runnable` object and schedule its `run()` method to be invoked by the Event Dispatch Thread.

**Event Dispatch Thread**

The reason to do this is that Swing objects are not thread-safe, i.e. not written to be handled by more than one thread at a time. Their methods, like `setVisible(true)` should be called by the Event Dispatch Thread, one at a time.

The event handling methods in listeners that you assign to Swing objects will be called on the Event Dispatch Thread. While they're being called, the Event Dispatch Thread is busy weaving through your event handler code, and not available to draw pixels on the screen or react to button clicks. Therefore, if you want your User Interface to be responsive, you should keep your event handling code short and quick.

If you want to run lengthy tasks, like reading a long file, or chat with the server, you should create and start a new Thread for this task to run in. This is called a Background or Worker thread. You can create a Runnable class for the job you want to run and feed it to the Thread you've created.

A somewhat more high-level way to schedule tasks is through the classes in the java.util.concurrent package, in particular the ExecutorService.

A good tutorial with more information is [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)